# How to get supervisord conf attributes in the process it is using?

Tags: python-2.7, logging, supervisord

`[program:automate_test_sessions_bigquery]
command=python2.7 -m a.process_name
autorestart=true
numprocs=2
stderr_logfile=/tmp/a.err.log
stdout_logfile=/tmp/a.out.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile_backups=0`

Above is a sample (partial) supervisord conf for a particular process. Now I am not able to make python2.7 logger to write logger.error logs into `a.err.log` and normal logs into `a.out.log`.

So I decided to split my logger into 2 stream object one writing into .err and other writing into .out files. All I need is value of `stderr_logfile` and `stdout_logfile` in the python process to determine the file names.

How can I do that ?